# Volume control over Bluetooth 4

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am designing a Bluetooth 4 heart rate monitor for use on a Android device.  I want to control the music playback volume on the android device by pushing a button on the heart rate monitor.  For example if the user decides to listen to a podcast on their android device while connected to the heart rate monitor and wants to change the volume he should be able to do this by pressing a button on the heart rate monitor.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the low level Gatt profile to user to transfer the button press information.  I don't know of anything suitable amongst the standard profiles but you should check carefully.  You will then need your hardware to implement the profile and then have some app running on the phone to pick up the other end and do the volume control which will be the easy bit.

It would be easier using ANT+ as there is a ready made profile for the control stuff that you could use (as well as HR) so no protocol design work needed.  You would also potentially be able to interface to any app with support for the ANT+ control profile as well as ANT+ HR.